# Backbone.js: Custom subscribing and publishing custom event between views / models

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, backbone-events

This is my case: I use jQuery.Forms to make an ajax call out of submitting a form. When the ajax call starts and returns, I need various Models / Views to respond to those events (the Model updates with data returned from the call, some controls are disabled and then enabled and so on).

I have the form mapped within a View. How can I trigger a custom `formSubmitting` "formSubmitted (with data)" even from the view and have any number of Models / Views responding to those events? What is the most idiomatic way of doing this with Backbone.js?

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
    window.UploaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.setElement(this.options.base_div);
            this.$el.find('form').ajaxForm({
                beforeSubmit: function() {
                    this.trigger('ajax-calling');
                },
                success: function(responseJSON) {
                    this.trigger('ajax-called', responseJSON);
                },
                dataType: 'json,'
            });
        },
    });

    var update_uploader = new window.UploaderView({
        base_div: $('#update-upload-action'),
    });

    var trigged = new window.UploaderView({
        parent_view: update_uploader,
        initialize: function() {
            this.options.parent_view.on('ajax-calling', function() {
                alert('calling!');
            });
        },
    });
```

But this does not work (no alert message is shown).

Comment: I Think there are some issues with sync there, if the `Trigged` view is not yet created and  `UploaderView` the ajax has returned sucess the listener is not yet in place and nothing will happen isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `initialize` function is never executed when your create new `window.UploaderView` instance, it is placed in view's options instead (see Backbone.js [View construction documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor)).

What you need is an event bus, single object inherited from `Backbone.Events` and available for all your views/models:

```
var eventBus = _.clone(Backbone.Events);

window.UploaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.setElement(this.options.base_div);
        this.$el.find('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit: function() {
                eventBus.trigger('ajax-calling');
            },
            success: function(responseJSON) {
                eventBus.trigger('ajax-called', responseJSON);
            },
            dataType: 'json,'
        });
    },
});

window.AnotherView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        eventBus.on('ajax-calling', this.ajaxCallingHandler);
    },
});

window.AnotherModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    eventBus.on('ajax-called', this.ajaxCallingHandler);
    },  
});
```

P.S. Please also note that ajaxForm `success` and `beforeSubmit` handlers in your example are executed with the scope of the ajax settings object. So you can't just use `this.trigger()` in them and would have to either bind these functions to `window.UploaderView` with `_.bind()` or use a closure. [More on scope binding](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX response is out of the scope of the view so "this" does not belongs to the view. Moving the responses to the view and applying _.bindAll(this); fixes your issues.

```
window.UploaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.setElement(this.options.base_div);
        this.$el.find('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit: this.onBeforeSubmit,
            success: this.onSuccess,
            dataType: 'json,'
        });
    },
    onBeforeSubmit : function() {
        this.trigger('ajax-calling');
    },
    onSuccess: function(responseJSON) {
        this.trigger('ajax-called', responseJSON);
    }
});

var update_uploader = new window.UploaderView({
    base_div: $('#update-upload-action'),
});

var trigged = new window.UploaderView({
    initialize: function() {
        this.options.parent_view.on('ajax-calling', function() {
            alert('calling!');
        });
    },
});
```